# Is there any replace function in list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Given a list of filenames, we want to rename all the files with extension hpp to the extension h. To do this, we would like to generate a new list called newfilenames, consisting of the new filenames. Fill in the blanks in the code using any of the methods you’ve learned thus far, like a for loop or a list comprehension.

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.
___  

print(newfilenames) 
# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
```

I only know how to find the names with .hpp extension but I don't know how to replace it with .h

```
newfilenames=[x for x in filenames if x.endswith('.hpp')]
```

Comment: As you'll probably deduce from the answers below, the list comprehension comprises both a filter and map (transformation) operation. Breaking it down:
[ <transform result -- single value> for <values in next expression> in <expression> if <filter condition> ]

Comment: You should try to solve this with a regular for-loop first. Then if you feel like it, try to turn it into a list comprehension. Note, sometimes list comprehensions get unreadable, although in this case, I think there is a fairly good solution. But don't feel like everything needs to be a list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is quite close, just need to use `.replace` and corrected the `if-else` position for more understanding.

Try this,

```
>>> [x.replace('.hpp', '.h') if x.endswith('.hpp') else x for x in filenames ]
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, all the other ones filter out those that don't end with `.hpp`!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```py
import re
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", 'example.hpp.c', "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
print([re.sub('.hpp$', '.h', filename) for filename in filenames])
```

Output:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'example.hpp.c', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Comment: This will transform `example.hpp.c` into `example.h.c`, which is probably not desired.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**Use** :

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
filenames = [i.replace(".hpp",".h") for i in filenames]
print(filenames)
```

**Solution**:

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Answer (score 0):

`[x.replace('.hpp', '.h') for x in filenames if x.endswith('.hpp')]`

When using list comprehension the first part before the `for` is where you put all of your code to modify the value of `x` before it goes into the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]  
[x[:-2] if x[-4:] == '.hpp' else x for x in filenames]
```

Output

```
['program.c', 'stdio.h', 'sample.h', 'a.out', 'math.h', 'hpp.out']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]   
newfilenames = [i.replace('.hpp','.h') for i in filenames]

# Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
print(newfilenames)
```

Comment: Code-only solutions are discouraged.  Please provide further context on what the code is doing for self-containment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = []
for name in filenames :
    
    if name[(name.index(".")):]== ".hpp" :
        newfilenames.append(name[:(name.index("."))]+".h")
        
    else:
        newfilenames.append(name) 
        
print(newfilenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
newfilenames = []
for x in filenames:
    if x.endswith('hpp'):
        newfilenames.append(x.replace('hpp', 'h'))
    else:
        newfilenames.append(x)
print(newfilenames)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
    new=[]
    for strings in filenames:
        if ".hpp" in strings:
            new=new+[strings[:-3]+"h"]
        else:
            new=new+[strings]
    print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is yet another way to approach the problem if one is not aware of the replace method, basically string slice the part you want. (list comprehension omitted here can also be achieved the same using the method)

> It also is much more efficient than than the replace method from memory and RAM point of view. (not that it matters here, but still good to know in order to build up complex systems)

```python
    filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp", "hpp.out"]
    # Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
    # using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.
    newfilenames = []
    newfilename = []
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.hpp'):
            new_filename = filename[:-2:]
            newfilenames.append(new_filename)
        else:
            newfilenames.append(filename)
    print(newfilenames)
    # Should be ["program.c", "stdio.h", "sample.h", "a.out", "math.h", "hpp.out"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filenames = ["program.c", "stdio.hpp", "sample.hpp", "a.out", "math.hpp",     
"hpp.out"]
# Generate newfilenames as a list containing the new filenames
# using as many lines of code as your chosen method requires.

print([x.replace(".hpp",".h") for x in filenames])
```